# Show My recently viewed Items on web page using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a web page, which shows list of all categories. Once the users click on any category, the related items below to that category are displayed. The categories and items are pulled using AngularJS.

I have a requirement to show the list of **5 most recently visited items** on the category page. This list should be based on the users. I mean for example if:

1. 'aaa' user is logged in, then he should get 5 most recently visited items he visited (if exist).
2. 'bbb' user is logged in, then he should get 5 most recently visited items he visited (if exist).

How to get this functionality in AngularJS. Should I create a service? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible, or at least post what you have tried so far (code)/what you're trying to do (more specifically). This way, it's more likely users on SO can help you.

Comment: Add the items in the array and show the items. At client side each user would have it's own session, so value would be unique.

Comment: @Agalo. Okay, I will add items to the array. But every time user refresh the page, the array will be empty right? How it works?

Comment: yes, that's true, you can make use of the `local storage` and get the data from there or use sessionStorage if multiple users are logging from the same machine.